# How to select objects if not exist between a period in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I like to select those users who haven't filled out a form in the last 7 days but I'm stuck. The background: I am working on an app that lists the users who have filled out the form but I wrote it in another query that works fine. Now I need to select just those users who haven't filled the form out in the last 7 days.
The query I wrote selects all the users because everyone has objects that outside the period.
How can I select just those users who haven't filled out the form in the given period but not to include all users. As you can see on the picture the user with `id 1` appears two times with `Yes` and `No`.
[image]

Tha query I wrote:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  auth_user.id,
   CASE WHEN felmeres.date BETWEEN date("now", "-7 day") AND date('now') 
   THEN 'Yes'
   ELSE 'No'
   END AS period
FROM felmeres
LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.user_id = felmeres.user_name_id
ORDER BY felmeres.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT p.user_id
FROM profile p
INNER JOIN felmeres f
    ON f.user_name_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY p.user_id
HAVING SUM(f.date BETWEEN date('now', '-7 day') AND date('now')) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `profile` contains the users' data then it should be the *left* table in the `LEFT` join and the condition for the dates should be placed in the `ON` clause, so that you filter out the matching users:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM profile p LEFT JOIN felmeres f
ON f.user_name_id = p.user_id AND f.date BETWEEN date(CURRENT_DATE, '-7 day') AND CURRENT_DATE 
WHERE f.user_name_id IS NULL;
```

Or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM profile p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM felmeres f
  WHERE f.user_name_id = p.user_id AND f.date BETWEEN date(CURRENT_DATE, '-7 day') AND CURRENT_DATE
);
```